# Pip shows package installed, python says it is not

Tags: python, pip, python-requests, centos7

I am trying to write a python script that includes `import requests`.  I have already installed it using `pip install requests` and a `pip freeze` shows the results below:

```
[rhanthony@python1 ~]$ pip freeze
--snip--
requests==2.8.1
--snip--
[rhanthony@python1 ~]$
```

This to me looks like it should be installed and working, however when I run my application with `uswgi -http 0.0.0.0:80 --wsgi-file app.py`, I get the following:

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "piql.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you use ``virtualenv``? If so , check if you are running ``uwsgi`` with the same virtualenv activated.

Comment: Also check that `pip` and `uswgi` use the same Python version!

Comment: Do `which pip` and `which python`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole virtual machine was cursed. There were apparently a ton of odd dependency breaks all over, and other nonsense.  Instead of working this problem further, and then moving on to countless others, the machine was scrapped and re-rolled.  Issue did not return.